# Intersection of polynomials with positive coefficients and different degrees

Tags: polynomials

This is a variation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005066/intersection-of-polynomials-with-positive-coefficients), but in my case I want to know if two polynomials of **different degrees** and **non-negative coefficients** can have more than one intersection in the positive $x$-axis.

For example, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDxCY.png) is the plot of the polynomials $15 x^4$ and $45 x^3 + 105 x^2 + 85 x + 25$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course they can. Say $3x$ and $x^2+2$. They intersect in $1$ and $2$:

$$ 3x=x^2+2\implies x^2-3x+2=0\implies (x-2)(x-1)=0$$

Comment: @user126444: You can get any number of intersections at any values of $x$ that you want!. Just find a polynomal that has roots at those $x$-values (like greedoid did for $x=1$ and $x=2$), then move the negative coefficients to the other side (that originally had the zero, just as greedoid did with the $-3x$ term).